# TI Launchpad MSP430 on Serial in Linux

Tags: usb, serial, uart, msp430, linux

The [MSP-EXP430G2 LaunchPad Experimenter Board User's Guide (Rev. C)](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau318c/slau318c.pdf) in chapter 3.2 states:

> The LaunchPad includes a pre-programmed MSP430G2553 device [...]
>
> Press button P1.3 to switch the application to a temperature
>   measurement mode. [...]
>
> The collected temperature data is
>   also communicated via back-channel UART through the USB emulation
>   circuitry back to the PC. The transmitted values [...] can be displayed with any terminal application or
>   the Temperature Sensor GUI available on the MSP430 LaunchPad wiki page
>   http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/MSP430_LaunchPad_(MSP-EXP430G2).
>   The serial communication port on the PC must be configured with 2400
>   bps, one stop bit, and no flow control to display the values
>   correctly.

I've been trying to connect to the serial communication channel from linux using PuTTY (/dev/ttyACM0, 2400Bd, 8N1), but nothing happens.

Similar results with:

```
stty /dev/ttyACM0 2400
screen /dev/ttyACM0
```

I haven't seen the LaunchPad USB serial working yet, so I'm trying to figure out whether the problem is with my Linux install or with the LaunchPad.

How can I read the data from the LaunchPad demo in Linux?

## EDIT1

I am on Ubuntu 12.10 64-bit

```
Linux 3.5.0-21-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 11 18:51:59 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


PACKAGE NAME      INSTALLED VERSION
binutils-msp430   2.22~msp20120406-2
gcc-msp430        4.6.3~mspgcc-20120406-3
gdb-msp430        7.2a~mspgcc-20111205-1ubuntu1
msp430-libc       20120224-1
msp430mcu         20120406-2
mspdebug          0.19-1
srecord
libsrecord-dev
libgmp-dev
```

Comment: I solved the problem. While writing this question, I was on the wrong track. Data didn't display because it is binary (in contrast to what the users guide implies) and because of buffer issues. I solved the issue by writing a short perl script, which I put on my personal blog: https://blog.linformatronics.nl/170/linux/ti-msp430-launchpad-temperature-demo-application

Answer (score 3):

This isn't too uncommon, especially if your system is a 64 bit system. Make sure you have these installed on your system:

- binutils-msp430
- gcc-msp430
- gdb-msp430
- msp430-libc
- msp430mcu
- mspdebug
- srecord
- libsrecord-dev
- libgmp-dev

After connecting the launchpad, it may take a bit of time (~1min or less) for the system to pick it up. What happens if you have a terminal open that is just monitoring the port like `cat /dev/ttyACM0`, and you connect/disconnect the unit a few times?

Are you sure you have everything else installed properly? You may need a few extra things if your system is 64 bit, and the newer kernel versions >2.4 may have a bit of a problem with some programs, but nothing that isn't easily fixed. Assuming you use some Debian distro,

```
sudo apt-get install subversion gcc-4.4 texinfo patch libncurses5-dev zlibc zlib1g-dev libx11-dev libusb-dev libreadline6-dev
```

There is a [How-to: Launchpad programming with Linux](http://hackaday.com/2010/08/11/how-to-launchpad-programming-with-linux/) article that may help.

Comment: Are you sure about the last three packages?

Comment: I managed to get some data using `minicom`. The LaunchPad spits out bytes, not ASCII data and no `CR` or `LF`. The lack of line terminators may very well explain why all the usual tools don't output anything (until the buffer is full).

Comment: @jippie The launchpad demo program doesn't send ASCII, it sends binary.

Comment: @jippie I'm not sure about the packages, it's been a while since I've played around with TI on a linux machine. I just found those from some site.